# ui-gmap-markers showing only one marker

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-ui, angular-google-maps

I am trying to display multiple markers on a map using ui-google-maps library for angular but it is showing only one marker.

```
<div  id="map_canvas" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
<h1 align="center">Maps</h1>
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="options">
<ui-gmap-markers models="rmarkers" coords="'self'"  fit='true' icon="'icon'">
</ui-map-markers>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>

<script>
angular.module('main', ['google-maps'.ns()])
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.map = {center: {latitude: 42.3349940452867, longitude: -71.0353168884369 }, zoom: 14 };
    //$scope.marker={id: 1, coords: {latitude: 42.3349940452867, longitude: -71.0353168884369 }};
    $scope.options = {scrollwheel: false};
     $scope.rmarkers=[{id: 101, latitude: 42.3349940452867, longitude: -71.0353168884369},
           {id: 102,latitide: 42.35114190333,longitude: -71.0662789402048},
           {id: 103,latitide: 43.35114190333,longitude: -72.0662789402048},
           {id: 104,latitide: 44.35114190333,longitude: -73.0662789402048}];});
```

Comment: I notice start tag <ui-gmap-markers .. but the closing tag is incorrect ? </ui-map-markers>, either start tag is </ui-map-markers>  or closing tag is  </ui-gmap-markers>

Answer (score 0):

if by 'ui-google-maps library for angular' you mean 
https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps

then this shows multiple markers on a map, adapting dome of your code to show running in a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/nigeljvm/duabubeo/9/

html layer

`<div ng-app="main" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true">
      <ui-gmap-marker ng-repeat="m in map.markersr" 
                                  coords="m" icon="m.icon" idkey="m.id">
      </ui-gmap-marker>
    </ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>`

javascript layer

```
angular.module('main', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps'])
.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {

angular.extend($scope, {
    map: {
        center: {
            latitude: 42.3349940452867,
            longitude:-71.0353168884369
        },
        zoom: 11,
        markersr: [
        {
            id: 101,
            latitude:  42.3349940452867,
            longitude:-71.0363168884369
        },    
        {
            id: 102,
            latitude:  42.3563941755867,
                  longitude:-71.0466168884469
        }, {
            id: 103,
            latitude:   42.3753940755867,
                  longitude:-71.0853168884369
        }, {
            id: 104,
            latitude:  42.3684940856867,
               longitude:-71.1273168884369
        }],
        dynamicMarkers: []
    }
});
```

});

css `.angular-google-map-container { height: 400px; }`

based on the angular-ui source 
https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/blob/master/example/assets/scripts/controllers/issue-74-markers-events.js

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. Replace "Latitide" with "latitude"